# WCF RIA Services -- take action when all data is loaded

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

So, I am just getting started with .WCF RIA Services and Silverlight.

Here's what I need to do:
I need to make a couple of calls to my domain service to load data.  So, I'm using the Load() method on the Context object.

I need to take some action when all of the queries have completed.  I see that I can specify a callback for each individual load, but what I really want to do is to register a callback that will be executed when all of the loads are complete.

Is there a built-in way to do this with RIA services/Silverlight, or will I need to roll my own?

BTW:  I'm not doing anything all that crazy -- I just don't want my form to be interactive until the data is loaded (I don't want to block the UI thread, I just want to show a progress bar/dancing hampster until all the data is loaded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smccraw/archive/2009/07/15/a-net-ria-services-data-load-batch-manager.aspx worked nicely for me.

If you don't want the users interacting with the page, use an activity indicator (I think it's in the Silverlight Toolkit now) to block the app while loading.

Comment: That code pretty much did what I had in mind.  It does have a potential race condition, though.  Since the loads are run immediately, it's unlikely, but possible that loads could complete before you are finished adding loads to the batch manager.  If it worked out so that the manager "looked" empty, that would cause the completed event to be raised prematurely.

Comment: Well, after further research, disregard my previous comment.  It looks as though the Load's don't run immediately, but after you return from the method that you were in.  Given that, I don't think that there is a race condition in that code.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built in so you would need to roll your own.

I guess you would bump a counter each time a query is kicked off and then inside the callback you decrease it again. If it hits zero then you fire an event saying there are no more outstanding requests.

Comment: That's what it looked like to me, too. So that makes me wonder if I'm doing something weird. My goal is simply that users shouldn't start interacting with the form until all the data is loaded. Is there some other way I should be doing that?

Comment: Sounds like the kind of thing that would be good to be added automatically by the generated code. But instead you need to add it yourself. Which is a shame.